# 2D Constructive Geometry Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, geometry

I'm trying to set up a simple 2D constructive geometry script, but running into some issues. I'm using a unit test in python to test some of my code, but running into errors, and wondering what I am doing wrong.

**1)** The class **'Union'** is suppose to determine if a point is inside a 'left' or 'right' node (which can be arbitrary, as I have many other shape functions that are based on the class QuadraticSurface), however for simplicity I have left the Circle definition in the code, as it is implemented in the unit test. For the case of the unit test, it creates two nodes, L and R, as denoted previously, but in this case, it is two circles centered at the origin, one with a radius of 1 and the other a radius of 2. For this specific case, it will read in three points ((0,0),(2,0),(1.5,0)). I have gone through many iterations, all have failed, giving me False is not True or vise versa, specifically for points (0,0) and (1.5,0). Basically, in the unit test, it is asserting the two circles form an annulus, and anything inside or outside the annulus is True, were anything in the annulus itself is False, aka point (1.5,0). This is what I have gathered from the Unit test myself, I could be wrong, I coded the above portion, the test file was given to me.

**2)** The class **'Intersection'** where contains should return true if the point is in both the left and right nodes. I have tried using the logical 'and', without success.

**3)** The class **'QuadraticSurface'** doesn't have an intersection function defined for a ray, and I'm a little lost on how to find the intersection points of some arbitrary shape. However, when the unit test runs, it passes it a ray, and a vertical plane at x=3, so with the ray it passes, the intersection point should wind up being (3,3).

**4)** *Useful Notes*: **Primitive** class represents a terminal node (surface). **Operator** class represents a combination of two nodes. **Operator**'s class should not implement its contains function, however, the interesctions function is to be in use.

**Update:** I tried the method Prune suggested, without success. The Unit Test returns AssertionError: True is not false for point (1.5,0). And for Intersections contains(p), False is not true for point (1.5,0).

**Base Code**

```
import numpy as np
import unittest

class Point(object) :

    def __init__(self, x, y) :
        self.x, self.y = x, y       
    def __add__(self,other):
        x = self.x + other.x
        y = self.y + other.y
        return Point(x,y)  
    def __mul__(self,scale):
        x = self.x * scale
        y = self.y * scale
        return Point(x,y) 
    def __str__(self) :
        return "Point(%.6F, %.6f) " % (self.x, self.y)

class Ray(object) :  
    def __init__(self, origin, direction) :
        self.origin = origin
        norm = np.sqrt(direction.x**2 + direction.y**2)
        self.direction = Point(direction.x/norm, direction.y/norm)
    def __str__(self) :
        return "Ray: r_0(%10.6f, %10.6f), d(%.6f %.6f) " % \
           (self.origin.x, self.origin.y, self.direction.x, self.direction.y)

class Node(object) :

    def contains(self, p) :
        raise NotImplementedError

    def intersections(self, r) :
        raise NotImplementedError

class Primitive(Node) :

    def __init__(self, surface, sense) :
        self.surface, self.sense = surface, sense

    def contains(self, p) :
        return (self.surface.f(p) < 0) == self.sense

    def intersections(self, r) :
        return self.surface.intersections(r)

class Operator(Node) :

    def __init__(self, L, R) :
        self.L, self.R = L, R

    def contains(self, p) :
        raise NotImplementedError

    def intersections(self, r) :
        # get intersections with left and right nodes
        pointsL = self.L.intersections(r)
        pointsR = self.R.intersections(r)
        # return the concatenated result
        return pointsL + pointsR

class Intersection(Operator):
    def __init__(self,L,R):
        super(Intersection,self).__init__(L,R)   
        self.L = L
        self.R = R

    def contains(self,p):
        return p >= self.L and p <= self.R

    def intersections(self):
        pass            
class Union(Operator):
    def __init__(self,L,R):    
        super(Union,self).__init__(L,R)
    def contains(self,p):
        return p <= self.L or p <= self.R

class Surface(object) :

    def f(self, p) :
        raise NotImplementedError

    def intersections(self, r) :
        raise NotImplementedError

class QuadraticSurface(Surface) :

    def __init__(self, A=0.0, B=0.0, C=0.0, D=0.0, E=0.0, F=0.0) :
        super(QuadraticSurface,self).__init__()
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C
        self.D = D
        self.E = E
        self.F = F

    def intersections(self, r) :
        self.r = r
        x = -self.F/self.D
        y = x

    def f(self, p) :
        x = p.x
        y = p.y
        return self.A*x**2 + self.B*y**2 + self.C*x*y + self.D*x + self.E*y + self.F

class Circle(QuadraticSurface):
    def __init__(self,r,a=0.0,b=0.0):
        super(Circle,self).__init__(A=0.0,B=0.0,C=0.0,D=0.0,E=0.0,F=0.0)
        self.r = r
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.A = 1.0
        self.B = 1.0
        self.C = 0.0
        self.D = -2.0*self.a**2
        self.E = -2.0*self.b**2
        self.F = self.r
```

**Unit Test**

```
class TestCSG(unittest.TestCase) :
    def setUp(self) :
        pass

    def get_circles(self) :
        # unit circle centered at origin
        c0 = Circle(1)
        # circle of radius two centered at the origin
        c1 = Circle(2)
        return c0, c1

    def testUnion_contains(self) :
        c0, c1 = self.get_circles()
        l, r = Primitive(c0, True), Primitive(c1, False)
        # everything outside c1 and inside c0
        u = Union(l, r)
        self.assertTrue(u.contains(Point(0, 0)))
        self.assertTrue(u.contains(Point(2, 0)))
        self.assertFalse(u.contains(Point(1.5, 0)))


    def testIntersection_contains(self) :

        c0, c1 = self.get_circles()
        l, r = Primitive(c0, False), Primitive(c1, True)
        # everything between c0 and c1
        i = Intersection(l, r)
        self.assertFalse(i.contains(Point(0, 0)))
        self.assertFalse(i.contains(Point(2, 0)))
        self.assertTrue(i.contains(Point(1.5, 0)))

    def testIntersection_intersections(self) :

        c0, c1 = self.get_circles()
        l, r = Primitive(c0, False), Primitive(c1, True)
        # everything between c0 and c1
        i = Intersection(l, r)
        # ray starting at (-3, 0) along x-axis
        ray = Ray(Point(-3, 0), Point(1, 0))

        # get intersections        
        ints = i.intersections(ray)
        # the order of the intersections depends on the implementation, but
        # the values should be unique.  hence, sort them according to 
        # x value.
        ints.sort(key = lambda p: p.x)
        reference_ints = [Point(i, 0) for i in (-2,-1, 1, 2)]        
        for i in range(4) :
            self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[i].x, reference_ints[i].x)

    def testQuadraticSurface_intersections(self) :

        # ray starting at origin and with a direction of 45 degrees
        ray = Ray(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1))

        # vertical plane at x = 3
        v = QuadraticSurface(D=1, F=-3)
        ints = v.intersections(ray)
        self.assertEqual(len(ints), 1)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[0].x, 3)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[0].y, 3)

        # create a circle of radius 2 centered at (2, 2)      
        c = QuadraticSurface(A=1, B=1, D=-4, E=-4, F=4)
        ints = c.intersections(ray)
        ints.sort(key=lambda p: p.x)
        self.assertEqual(len(ints), 2)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[0].x, (np.sqrt(8)-2)*np.cos(np.pi/4))
        self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[0].y, (np.sqrt(8)-2)*np.sin(np.pi/4))     
        self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[1].x, (np.sqrt(8)+2)*np.sin(np.pi/4))
        self.assertAlmostEqual(ints[1].y, (np.sqrt(8)+2)*np.sin(np.pi/4))

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  In this posting, you've handicapped us by including superfluous code, omitting documentation, and not tracing your program operation.

Comment: Could you please remove or fix the unit tests with syntax errors?  Those are the two tests of "intersections".

Comment: Syntactical errors? I'm not quite sure what you mean, when I run the entire script (I use the Base class and Test Class in one script), it runs without any syntactical errors when I copy directly from this page. What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Wrong number of arguments to "intersections".  The class methods take no arguments, but you're passing one in.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems with the code.  The immediate one is that, although I can't figure out your class and object architecture, I can see a functional problem with **contains**.  Using Union as the example, let's look at the critical line.  I added a print statement in front to see what we were comparing (which you should have done in tracing your program).

```
print p, self.L, self.R
if p <= self.L or self.R:
```

p is a point; self.L, and self.R are primitives without a useful representation.

```
Point(1.500000, 0.000000)  <so.Primitive object at 0x2671c50> <so.Primitive object at 0x2671c90>
```

I don't see a definition of <= for point and object, but it seems to be membership.  However, the second part is incorrect: self.R is not a boolean value.  You cannot distribute an arbitrary operation over "and" and "or".  I think what you need is

```
if p <= self.L or p <= self.R:
```

In fact, note that you can just return this value, making your entire function

```
def contains(self,p):
    return p <= self.L or p <= self.R
```

I hope this clears up your problem.  BTW, your problem with the Intersection function is that it doesn't return anything.  I suggest that you do the same as the code just above, using "and" in place of "or".

Finally, *please* attempt to debug the problem yourself before posting: add print statements to track parameter values at the top of each problem method, and print statements to report the return values at the end.  Check each stage in a failing expression.

Most of all, make sure your code is properly documented when you post here.  I could possibly find more problems after the immediate ones if I had some idea of how your stuff works.

---

I tried that comparison function with various points.  All of them give the same expression results:

```
p <= <circle_object> returns True
p >= <circle_object> returns False
```

Now that you've described your code better, I can see the problem: you haven't defined the "<=" and ">=" operators for the class.  This means that you're simply comparing object handles; the result says nothing about whether the point is inside or outside the circle.

See how you've defined operators in class Point?  You need to do something like this for comparing against a Surface, too.

Comment: Prune, I apologize for the 'ugliness' of my post, which is entirely my fault. I posted this right before bed, which probably wasn't the best choice. I edited my post, and hopefully clarified some things, and what they are meant to do. As for debugging, I have tried printing at the top and bottom for specific things, however I excluded it from the code posted here, as it is already longer than what most people would want to read. Thank you for the link to the MCVE. Thank you for the help, I appreciate you even taking the time to help me fixing a problem I didn't do a good job of explaining.

Comment: Much better!  I'm still not clear what you expect for intersection semantics; a couple of your pronoun uses are ambiguous.  The unit tests are indicative, but hardly self-explanatory.  Also, that last sentence of point 4, the one on Operators, just doesn't resolve semantically.

Comment: Prune, welcome to my world. As for the intersection semantics, all the information I provided is what I was told to implement, the instructions don't go much further than that. As for the Quadratic intersections, it should work for any arbitrary surface, given by the function 'f(p)' in the QuadraticSurface class. As for the Operator class, what I'm told is, like the Node class, Operator is an abstract class (C-speak, it’s like having a function declaration in a header without its deﬁnition in the source ﬁle), because its contains its not implemented in this class.

Comment: Yup.  I know what an abstract class is.  I also can see quite simply that those comparison functions don't work the way you thought.  If there is a definition of those up the line somewhere, you need to find it and see what it does.  Otherwise, you need to implement your own "is the point inside the surface?" method.

Comment: Sorry! I knew you probably knew what an abstract class was, I was just saying the information I was given! My knowledge breadth isn't as far reaching as yours. However, despite the code I provided, I really don't know to much about python. The class I'm in is VERY fast paced (grad level class), and we covered OOP in under a day (no prior experience). Could you explain what you mean by my comparison functions not working the way I thought? And what you mean by there is a definition of those up the line somewhere. I get lost with all the classes inheriting from others, with such limited OOP exp

Comment: Also, in regards your comment "you haven't defined the "<=" and ">=" operators for the class." Could you go into more depth on this? I realize these are pretty stupid questions, but I really am trying to learn. I understood when I implemented 'function overloading', aka what your talking about when I did it with the point class, but not sure how to implement it with what you are referring too. Sorry about all the questions, I know you could be utilizing your time better with more interesting concepts on this site, but any help I can get to learn is greatly appreciated! Thank you again.

Comment: These are the comparison functions to which I just referred.  In general, these are defined for compatible numeric values -- but you seem to think that they can also denote whether a point is inside a circle.  I don't see any such definition, and my experimenting shows that they don't work the way you expected.

Comment: Notice how you redefined __add__ and the other basic arithmetic operations to work on a point and a scalar?  You can do the same with the comparison operations, if you know their true names.  Look for something like __lessequal__.  However, I think it's a better idea to write your own and give it a more meaningful name, such as Point.isInside(Surface).